# #define not working as expected after #undef using #ifndef

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I wrote a simple program to change addition to multiplication

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ADD(X,Y) X+Y

void fun()
{
    #ifndef ADD(X,Y)
        printf("entered #ifndef");
        #define ADD(X,Y) X*Y;
    #endif

    int y=ADD(3,2);
    printf("%d",y);
}

int main()
{
    #undef ADD(X,Y)
    fun();

    return 0;
}
```

The output I expect is `3*2` but the code still outputs `3+2` i.e. 5 .
The code doesn't output : `"entered #ifndef"`, that means `#undef` is not working?
What is wrong here?

**Edit :**
Thanks to @deviantfan

Here is the correct code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ADD(X,Y) X+Y

void fun();

int main()
{
    #undef ADD(X,Y)
    fun();

    return 0;
}

void fun()
{
    #ifndef ADD(X,Y)
        printf("entered #ifndef");
        #define ADD(X,Y) X*Y;
    #endif

    int y=ADD(3,2);
    printf("%d",y);
}
```

Comment: *warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive [-Wextra-tokens]*

Comment: `#undef` does nothing here. Preprocessor directives are processed as they go in a code, regargless if they are inside functions (`fun()` in your case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor (which processes eg `#define`) doesn´t know about
functions or things like that. It processes the file strictly from top to bottom,
independent how the actual code execution would jump around at runtime.

As soon as it hits your `#undef`, the `#ifndef` is long forgotten and won´t be evaluated again.

Answer (score 2):

The actual solution to this problem is to use function pointers.

Here is a direct translation from your current code to function pointers.

Note the similarities and differences.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int actual_add(int X, int Y) {
   return X+Y;
}

int actual_multiply(int X, int Y) {
   return X*Y;
}

int (*ADD)(int,int) = actual_add;

void fun()
{
    if (!ADD)
    {
        printf("entered #ifndef");
        ADD = actual_multiply;
    }

    int y=ADD(3,2);
    printf("%d",y);
}

int main()
{
    ADD = NULL;
    fun();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#ifdef`, `#ifndef` and `#undef` preprocessor directives expect an identifier, not an expression.

`#ifndef ADD(X,Y)` is meaningless.

It should read: `#ifdef ADD`.

The same goes for `#undef ADD`